# React multiple children sends the same props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my React App I fetch the data from the api and list all the posts in main page, so my intention is create a function that rates the post with stars. So I am mapping all the posts and
passing the post infos to `Rate` component and with `ratePost` action I rate the post.

**action**

```
export const ratePost = (rate, postId) => dispatch => {
    const config = {
        withCredentials: true
    }

    const sRate = parseInt(rate, 10)

    const body = JSON.stringify({ star_rate:sRate })

    axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/p/rate/${postId}`, body, config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: RATE_POST,
                sRate,
                postId
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            dispatch({
                type: RATE_POST_FAIL
            })
        })
}
```

However the problem is when I dispatch the action it always sends the same `postId` and after console logging the props it shows same `props` even I rate different posts.

In React DevTools Components section it shows multiple `Rate` components and their props is different as expected.(I cut the unrelated part of the code)

```
export function Card(props) {

    const { category } = useParams()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!category){
            props.getPosts()
        } else {
            props.getPostsByCategory(category)
        }
    },[category])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="posts">
                {props.posts.map(post => 
                    <article key={post.id} id={post.id}>
                        <div className="post-meta">
                            <div className="stars">
                                <Rate post={post}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                )}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
    
}
```

**Rate.js**

```
export function Rate(props) {

    const onInput = (e) => {
        props.ratePost(e.target.value, props.post.id)
        console.log(props.post) /* shows the same props */
    }

    return(
        <fieldset className="rating">
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label className = "full" htmlFor="star5"></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star4half" name="rating" value="4.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor="star4half" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label className = "full" htmlFor="star4" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star3half" name="rating" value="3.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor="star3half" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label className = "full" htmlFor="star3" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star2half" name="rating" value="2.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor="star2half" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label className = "full" htmlFor="star2" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star1half" name="rating" value="1.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor="star1half" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label className = "full" htmlFor="star1" ></label>
            <input type="radio" onInput={onInput} id="starhalf" name="rating" value="0.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor="starhalf"></label>
        </fieldset>
    )
}
export default connect(null, { ratePost })(Rate)
```

Comment: You aren't showing how you are passing the `ratePost` prop to the `Rate` component - `mapDispatchToProps` maybe?

Comment: I edited the question, there is no problem at sending the request tho. Problem is it sends the same `postId` even I click on different posts.

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine, you're doing something else wrong. If you can reproduce a minimal example on something like stackblitz then you'll get more help. But I have a feeling that if you try to do that you'll find the mistake you made along the way.

Comment: Here's a minimal stackblitz that reproduces what you've essentially shown in your code - open the console and check the `./store` file - see? everything works. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zzcska?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Now I'm really confused about why this is not working.

Comment: Walk through it - this is basic debugging - does the correct stuff come out in the console in the `onInput` method? If so, put a `console.log` in your `ratePost` - maybe you have two `ratePost`'s and are importing the wrong one. The point is, SO can't help you anymore because the code you are showing will work, as long as it's all wired together correctly - e.g. the imports/exports are in the proper places.

Comment: Out of `onInput` `console.log` logs all posts, however in the `onInput` it only logs first post and I couldn't find out what the solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, the problem was `id` of `inputs`. They needed to be unique so I updated my code like that =>

```
return(
    <fieldset className="rating" >
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star5"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="5" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star5"+props.post.id}></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star4half"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="4.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star4half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star4"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="4" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star4"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star3half"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="3.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star3half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star3"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="3" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star3"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star2half"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="2.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star2half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star2"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="2" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star2"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star1half"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="1.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star1half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star1"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="1" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star1"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"starhalf"+props.post.id} name="rating" value="0.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"starhalf"+props.post.id}></label>
    </fieldset>
)
```